# Image size reduction by grayscale

Tags: java, android

All welcome.

There is such code:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data,Camera camera){
    try{
        YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,this.width,this.height,null);
        System.out.println("WidthandHeight"+yuvimage.getHeight()+"::"+yuvimage.getWidth());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,this.width,this.height),100,baos);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("parse","errpr");
    }
}
```

It takes the image from the camera and turns it into a jpg image.

But here's the problem:

The image, even if its quality is shrunk to 20 percent, weighs about 2 kb (2000 bytes).

As I understand it, the weight of the image consists of:

> width * length * 3 (3 - three channels. R, G, B).

In fact, if you make the image black and white, the formula will be:

> width * length * 1 (one channel)

That is, thereby, reducing the size of the image by 3 times!

I tried to do this.

But after checking, it turned out that the image became black-and-old, but the size was as it was and remained about 2 kb.

Code (from RGB to grayscale):
 
    public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
    {
        int width, height;
        height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
        width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();

```
    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

What could go wrong? Is it possible to reduce the weight of the image in this way?

Comment: You're encoding it as NV21 so of course the image size isn't going to be directly related to RGB. It's not encoded in those terms.

Comment: @Michael, ohh... That is, nothing can be done?